# Union and Difference in Set Theory

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let x ∈ A. {x,x,x,x,x} ∪ {x,x} = {x,x,x,x,x,x,x}
This statement is false right? Because the union of two sets is a set of the first and second set's elements with no elements repeating. I guess I am confused because x seems to be an arbitrary value.

Let x ∈ A. {x,x} / {x} = {x}
Would this also be false? Because If the set difference is removing every element of the second set from the first, x is seen in both sets so the result would have to be an empty set. Again, I am confused because x seems to be arbitrary.

Comment: In set theory an element of a set is counted only one. See [Extensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality)

Comment: Thus, $\{ x,x \} = \{ x \}$

Comment: So what I'm understanding is multiplicity is not accounted for in sets? If I now take that and apply it to the questions then the first statement becomes {x} ∪ {x} which is equivalent to just {x}?

Comment: Correct........

Comment: For multiplicity, see [Multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first statement is, in a sense, true.  {x, x, x, x, x}= {x} and {x,x}={x} so that ${x, x, x, x, x}\cup {x, x}= {x}\cup{x}= {x}$, and that is, indeed, equal to {x, x, x, x, x, x, x}!  That's just a very silly way of writing "${x}\cup{x}= {x}$".

But you are correct that {x, x}{x}= {x} is false. {x, x}{x} is the same as {x}{x} which is the empty set, not {x}.